# не включается навигация в owl carousel

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

как включить навигацию ? сама карусель появилась и все ок, но навигация не появляется, как быть?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
              $("#owl-example").owlCarousel({
                items : 4,
                loop: true,
                autoplay: false,
                autoplayTimeout: 3000,
                nav: true,

              });
            });
</script>
```

```css
.slider__div {
 height: 100px;
 background-color: white;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/owl.theme.default.css">

<div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel">
                     <div class="slider__one"></div>
                     <div class="slider__two"></div>
                     <div class="slider__three"></div>
                     <div class="slider__four"></div>
</div>

<script src="js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

В owl-carousel_1 - навигация включается опцией *navigation*

В owl-carousel_2 - навигация включается опцией *nav*

Можно так же включить навигацию вручную, добавив к кастомным элементам следующий код js, например:

```
var owl_review = $("#owl-review"); //блок с каруселью

owl_review.owlCarousel({ //инициализируем карусь
    items: 3,
});

//добавляем к кнопкам в блоке с каруселью обработчики
$(".next-review").click(function() { 
    owl_review.trigger('owl.next');
});

$(".prev-review").click(function() {
    owl_review.trigger('owl.prev');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас в коде один item(слайд), то навигация не включится. Добавьте еще слайдов пару.

Answer (score 0):

А в скрипте вызывающем карусель случайно не **navigation** вместо **nav** должно быть?

[Тут](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#customizing) посмотрите кастомизацию.

Вот так:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
              $("#owl-example").owlCarousel({
                items : 4,
                loop: true,
                autoplay: false,
                autoplayTimeout: 3000,
                navigation: true,

              });
            });
</script>
```